# Css position absolute leaves white space at the top

Tags: css, css-position

I want to absolute position a div but it is not sticked to the top but has a blank space. Container has `position:relative` and inner block has `position:absolute` css rules. I tried to play with the code and noticed that changing background-position has some effect and I have no idea why.

```
<header>
   <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-slogan-1 text-center">Base info</div>
   <div class="header-info">Info</div>
   </div>
</header>
```

What I want is to have the green block at the top (see fiddle).

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b5t66rs/)

Please can anyone explain the behaviour and answer why the block is shifted from the top?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I suppose changing `margin-top` to `padding-top` of `.header-slogan-1` element will do the job. But behaviour of `position:relative` still remains tricky for me.

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: It is not completely clear to me why coordinate origin starts 88px below top border and background is shaded from the top. From my point of view it should correspond. If the wrapper is shifted it should be shaded accordingly. If not, it should start at 0px from the top and should not have margin. It's a bit tricky. But it's ok, I can close the question.

Comment: "From my point of view it should correspond." But clearly this is not how css works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shifted from the top, because it is relative to its parent `.header-wrapper`, that has a top margin. In order to get the desired result, you have to remove `position: relative` from its parent, therefore it will be relative to the viewport and will be placed at the top.

Edit: I realised, that he margin is actually applied to the child of the wrapper, causing [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). In order to fix this, you need apply `overflow: auto` to the parent element. By doing that, you can still have a `position: relative` on the wrapper, as it is not pushed down by the child. Take a look at the demo:

```css
/* header block */
header {
    height: 536px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 536px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header .header-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}

.header-slogan-1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 88px;
}

.header-wrapper .header-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #4caf50;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 75px;
    color: #fff;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
   <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-slogan-1 text-center">Base info</div>
       
       
   <div class="header-info">Info</div>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: But the wrapper does not have margin? I don't see it. `.header-slogan-1` has margin-top property but it`s not the wrapper.

Comment: You're right, you can fix that with `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the header to have no space around it. If this is the case, then just add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to the top of your css and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `margin-top: 88px;` into `padding-top: 88px;` of `header-slogan-1` as it does not change my layout. I have an image in wrapper class and it is centered and may exceed the container size, so I need `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden`.

Finally I decided to pick my solution. Sorry Adam for not choosing your answer.